# Idle state in RTOS, sleep state or lowest frequency?

Tags: rtos

In real time systems using an RTOS, what how would the RTOS handle an idle period? Would it run nop instructions at the lowest frequency supported by a Dynamic Voltage Scaling capable processor? or would it turn to a sleep state? Can anyone refer me to actual practical implementations. Thanks

Comment: In his blog, Nigel Jones suggested [What to do in the Idle Task](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2013/04/idling-along/).

Answer (score 1):

It will depend entirely on the target hardware and possibly the needs and design of the application.  For example on ARM Cortex-M you would *typically* invoke the WFI instruction which shuts down the core until the occurrence of an interrupt.

In many microcontroller/SoC cases, reducing the PLL clock frequency would affect the on-chip peripherals from which hardware interrupts might occur, so that is less likely.  It would affect baud rates and timer resolution, and is perhaps hard to manage easily.  There is a paper [here](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1451-4869/2013/1451-48691301199S.pdf) on a *tickless idle* power management method on FreeRTOS/Cortex-M3.

In most cases the idle loop source is provided as part of the board-support, so you can customise it to your needs.